# How to draw particular or multiple contours of objects

Tags: python, opencv

I can't seem to find a way to draw more than one contour of objects.

Input Image:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
img = cv2.imread('img.png', 0)

#Thresh
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Finding the contours in the image
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Convert img to RGB and draw contour
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (0,0,255), 2)

#save output img
cv2.imwrite('output_img.png', img)
```

Output:

[image]

Only the larger object contour is drawn. How would I draw both contours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the third parameter to -1(third argument is index of contours) in your [drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) which will draw all contours in your image:

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

If you want to draw only two contours and the first two contours are of the white objects use:

```
cnt1 = contours[0]
cnt2 = contours[1]
cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt1, cnt2], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Sir.