# crop the border of image python

Tags: python, image, opencv, border, crop

I have this picture
[image]

and I want to crop it like this
[image]

I use this code, but it doesn't crop the black border. so, can someone help me?

```
    im = cv2.imread("Data/"+file, 0)
    retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(im, thresh=100, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    points = np.argwhere(thresh_gray==0)
    points = np.fliplr(points)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(points)
    crop = im[y:y+h, x:x+w] # create a crop
    retval, thresh_crop = cv2.threshold(crop, thresh=200, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    path = 'D:\Picture\Camera Roll'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , file),thresh_crop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html#contours-hierarchy) for your solution The contours are a curve/line joining continuous points of same intensity. So the box enclosing the written script is one contour. The contours in an image also have relationships like one contour could be a parent of other contour(s). In your image, the box could be the parent of the written script.

cv2.findContours finds all the contours in an image and the second parameter(cv2.RETR_TREE) is to mention what kind of relationships should be returned. As the contours have an hierarchy, it's likely that the box will be in index 0 or 1 of the contours list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image]

I though the the first contour(contours[0]) would represent the box, but for some reason it's the second one.

```
img_copy = img.copy()
cnt= contours[1]
cv2.drawContours(img_copy, [cnt], -1, color = (255, 255, 255), thickness = 20)
plt.imshow(img_copy, 'gray')
```

[image]

After you have the contours, just draw a thick white line over the contour to remove the box. Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581334/how-to-draw-particular-or-multiple-contours-of-objects/53581376#53581376) to draw specific contours on a image

> Don't worry about the bounding box in these images. It's just matplotlib. Your image is what is inside the coordinate box.

Comment: @AmyDafe oh I see. Can you mention that in your question too so that others are aware of it? I'll also try to find a solution to this problem

Comment: ah I forgot to mention it i'm sorry. but thank you for answering

Comment: it didn't :( I think i'm going to use with the border. thank you for trying to help. I really appreciated it :)