# How do i display multiple contour using python and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to show the difference in the image as a contour.
And I want to keep the contour from the previous frame so it doesn't go away, so it's updated **every frame.**
For example, the contour representing the difference between frame1 and frame2 is red,
The contour showing the difference between frame2 and frame3 is shown in blue in the video image.

[image]

```
frame2-frame1 = red contour
frame3-frame2 = blue contour

=========================

frame3-frame2= red contour
frame4-frame3 = blue contour
```

How can I modify the code?
Thank you for any comment.

```
        diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 15, 255, 0)
        roi = img_binary[y:y+h+3, x:x+w+10]
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.drawContours(frame2, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2, offset=(x,y))  # blue 
        frame1=frame2
```

Comment: you can append contours to a list and display it in the end. Does this answer your ques : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581334/how-to-draw-particular-or-multiple-contours-of-objects